# How to check if all the elements in list in one pandas column are present in another pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a lists in one column of a dataframe `df1`, and I want to check to see for each row if all elements of that list are in another column that is in a second dataframe `df2`.

The two dataframes are something like this:

```
df1                                          df2

id | members      |                          num  |  available           |
1  |['a',b']      |                          one  | ['a','b','c','d','e']|
2  |['b']         |                          two  | ['a','b']            |
3  |['a','b','c'] |                          three| ['b','d','e']        |
```

I am trying to come up with a method that can give me which rows in `df2` have all elements of `members` for each row in `df1`. Maybe something that yields this:

```
id | members      | which_cols            |                
1  |['a',b']      | ['one','two']         |                       
2  |['b']         | ['one','two','three'] |                         
3  |['a','b','c'] | ['one']               |
```

I thought converting it into dictionaries like `{k: list(v) for k,v in df1.groupby("id")["members"]}` and `{i: list(j) for i,j in df2.groupby("num")["available"]}` might make it more flexible to achieve the desired output but still haven't found a method to get to what I'm looking for.

`df2` will have about `300` rows with length of `available` being as large as `25,000`. And `df1` can be as big as `1M` rows with list length in `members` up to 15. So I think efficiency will also be important.

Comment: `c` does not appear in `two`?

Comment: Just added some more info on the data.

Comment: It's interesting that your `members` are a lot more abundant than `available`. You can make your problem a little easier by filtering out all `members` lists with length more than `15` as they wouldn't fit in any of `available`.

Comment: that was another mistake on my part. It is the other way around. `available` will be like a master list and `members` are subsets but they are not all in all rows of `df2`

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem lies in your data setup.  If you do a bit of preprocessing, you can avoid tediously iterating through every list multiple times over.

### Setup

```
df1 = pd.Series([['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], name = 'members').to_frame()
df2 = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
                  ['a', 'b'],
                  ['b', 'd', 'e']], name = 'available').to_frame()
df2.index = ['one', 'two', 'three']

>>> df1

    members
0   ['a', 'b']
1   ['b']
2   ['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> df2

        available
one.    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
two     ['a', 'b']
three   ['b', 'd', 'e']
```

### Reshape Data

If you one-hot encode your data before working with it, you put yourself at a great advantage for doing subset checks:

```
# You can do this many ways, but sklearn makes this very easy with:
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df1.pop('members')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_, index=df1.index))

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df2 = df2.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df2.pop('available')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_, index=df2.index))

>>> df1
    a   b   c
0   1   1   0
1   0   1   0
2   1   1   1


>>> df2
        a   b   c   d   e
one     1   1   1   1   1
two     1   1   0   0   0
three   0   1   0   1   1
```

### Calculation

The clever thing about this data format, is that now you can subtract `df1` from `df2` and if none of your resultant values are -1 (indicating a lack of an element in `df2`, then you add that to the list. Think of this as overlaying the two dataframes (aligning each resource) and then subtracting. And of course, this can be vectorized:

```
>>> df1.apply(lambda row: df2.index[((df2[df1.columns] - row) >= 0).all(axis = 1)], axis = 1)

0   Index(['one', 'two'], dtype='object')
1   Index(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype='object')
2   Index(['one'], dtype='object')
```